# APP_CMD_WINDOW_RESIZED is not called but native window is resized

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-activity

I've native app, which is configured to not destroy activity on device orientation change.

```
<activity android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
    ...
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    ...
    >
```

When the devices orientation changes **only** following Native life-cycle command is triggered.

```
/**
 * Command from main thread: the current device configuration has changed.
 */
APP_CMD_CONFIG_CHANGED
```

In the command handler I can see that the window size has been changed with `ANativeWindow_getHeight` function.

*(I know that `ANativeWindow_getHeight` function is not the best idea to use in config change handler to get the window size, I just only need to check if the window has been resized.)*

If the native windows is resized I suppose following native command should be triggered ?

```
/**
 * Command from main thread: the current ANativeWindow has been resized.
 * Please redraw with its new size.
 */
APP_CMD_WINDOW_RESIZED
```

Why it has been blocked ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out the reason myself,

The android native app glue does not have a code for firing `APP_CMD_WINDOW_RESIZED` command. But only has the definition for it.

The reason for that, is because [app glue code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/ndk/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c) does not register the native callback `onNativeWindowResized`

```
void ANativeActivity_onCreate(ANativeActivity* activity, 
                             void* savedState, size_t savedStateSize) {
    LOGV("Creating: %p\n", activity);
    activity->callbacks->onDestroy = onDestroy;
    activity->callbacks->onStart = onStart;
    activity->callbacks->onResume = onResume;
    activity->callbacks->onSaveInstanceState = onSaveInstanceState;
    activity->callbacks->onPause = onPause;
    activity->callbacks->onStop = onStop;
    activity->callbacks->onConfigurationChanged = onConfigurationChanged;
    activity->callbacks->onLowMemory = onLowMemory;
    activity->callbacks->onWindowFocusChanged = onWindowFocusChanged;
    activity->callbacks->onNativeWindowCreated = onNativeWindowCreated;
    activity->callbacks->onNativeWindowDestroyed = onNativeWindowDestroyed;
    activity->callbacks->onInputQueueCreated = onInputQueueCreated;
    activity->callbacks->onInputQueueDestroyed = onInputQueueDestroyed;
    activity->instance = android_app_create(activity, savedState, savedStateSize); 
}
```

And finally the reason why it does not register for it is an android bug described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180645)

The documentation of native callbacks is [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/struct_a_native_activity_callbacks.html#ab7bd120b8816508561126308f699f116)

Comment: I can't prove it, but I suspect that bug report is slightly inaccurate, and that surfaceChanged just isn't being called more than once on app startup. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137515/android-ndk-handling-orientation-change